# How to disable landscape mode for Android tablets?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I want to disable landsacpe mode for phones and tablets, but when I use this code below, and run applicaton on 10" tablet i get inverted layout.

```
<activity android:name="com.zookey.mathgenius.activities.LocalGameActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"                 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"></activity>
```

How I can fix this?

IMAGE:

[dodaj.rs/f/2G/En/2lqYaW1v/inverted.png](http://dodaj.rs/f/2G/En/2lqYaW1v/inverted.png)

Comment: define 'inverted layout' (are you holding your tablet upside down?)

Comment: You could try `android:screenOrientation="reversePortrait"` and see what happens.

Comment: just to know... can you give some details about the hardware your're using? I had a similar problem with my cheap China tablet, not resolved.

Comment: Actually, I am using emulator. But here is what I mean by "inverted layout", anyway when I run 10" Android tablet emulator it starts automatically in "landsacpe mode" but I force it with CTRL + F11 to back to portrait. Here is SCREENSHOOT: http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2G/En/2lqYaW1v/inverted.png

Comment: And when I use printscreen through emulator, here is what I get http://www.dodaj.rs/f/3G/2y/4lUgTWas/inverted.png

Comment: Have you tried rotating it twice more? Maybe the emulator only supports one way portrait.

Comment: Do you have tablet to send you .apk to try it?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the orientation programmatically you can use the following code :

```
//Disables screen orientation change based on sensor
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

//Sets the screen orientation to portrait
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

//Sets the screen orientation to inverted portrait
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT);

//Let system decide the orientation (when you are done)
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
```

Comment: Its same for both screen_orientation_portrait & screen_orientation_reverse_portrait ? I hope you are using only one of the option at a time ;)

Comment: I tried with these:  //Disables screen orientation change based on sensor
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

//Sets the screen orientation to portrait
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: try:     setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR); setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT); If it still doesn't work, try it on a real device and not an emulator. I've used this code and it works for me on real device.